# How come this mail system isn't working in PHP?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to get data from the form I have done to get emailed to my personal email, so every time it gets filled in, it gets emailed to me, So far I've wrote the following code in the php section in my website, but when I submit my form data, it stores correctly in the variables but it doesn't mail me the information? can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
<?php
$to = "example@hotmail.com"; //Removed personal email, didn't want to share publicly
$subject = "Form results";
$message = "Data from form"
. $firstname
. $surname
. $comments
. $email
. $password;

$from = "example@hotmail.com"; //removed this one too, but u get the idea
$headers = "From: " . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "mail Sent.";
?>
```

Comment: Probably because of `$message = "Data from form"` you're closing your quotes without the other info you want included inside.

Comment: Just a note: if your using Xampp or Wampp, they dont support the mail function in php

Comment: Are there any errors being generated by the `mail()` function?  I notice you don't check its return value, did you check the logs?  If you point it to a fake SMTP server that you can control for debugging, what happens on that server?  There could be *tons* of things preventing an email from reaching your inbox, most of which aren't necessarily related to this code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What? He's concatenating the string with the other variables

Comment: @Fred-ii- - but he's appending all the other info; variables don't need to be inside the quotes; what he's done is a perfectly valid way of adding to a variable.

Comment: Off Topic: This looks like a bad phishing attempt. :P

Comment: @JeroenBollen - there are a number of perfectly reasonable uses for this kind of code. For example, survey results that need to be sent to a customer service email.

Comment: Well, the variables aren't defined. So, something's missing in the OP's code, IF that's the entire code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, you're right. But that wouldn't prevent the email from being sent.

Comment: @EmmyS He sent the pass.

Comment: @NoLiver92 You're actualy wrong. U have to configure the PHP ini with a valid SMTP host to make it work

Comment: Ok... well the code checks out, I just tested it. So the problem is elsewhere. Could be 1 of 100 reasons.

Comment: at fred-ii- Yeah, This ain't the entire code, I've only included the mail coding, the rest wasn't needed to be put up, I've got no problems with the rest, everything stored well to my variables, I tested them with the echo function before trying to set up the mail feature... @NoLiver92, I'm just using it on my own server, used Winscp to upload it, but some reason it doesn't work ? Anyone know the solution ?

Comment: Check your `.ini` files then and other server settings. My server sent out the mail with no hitches. @user2985995

Comment: what do the mail server logs say?>

Comment: @JeroenBollen It's not for phishing at the slightest, I've got no reason to waste my time trying to hack peoples passwords using a basic form, theres plenty of pre-written code on the internet for that anyways.

Comment: Adding a condition **"may"** help to see if mail did execute `if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) { echo "mail Sent."; } else { echo "Sorry"; }` @user2985995

Comment: Yeah just tried this now, It says the mail is sent but when I check my emails, nothing is there? I'm not sure if the server I am running the form off is blocking it or some sort :/

Comment: mail function returning true tells you very little, check the server mail logs.

Comment: I did say "may" ;-) @Dagon it's not a "for sure" thing. I agree though, checking the mail logs is the way to check.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the help, And thanks to everyone else who tried to help, I'll just try messing around with the server now that I know the code is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need this to enable email features on WAMP server.

http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-using-wamp-server/

Do check them out.

Your code seems to be just fine.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll check them out, I thought my code seemed fine myself, I think your probably right, It's getting blocked by the looks of it, I'll give them blogs a read, thanks again

Comment: I had a similar problem for my project once. 
Checked out Gmail and it's SMTP settings, added this PHPMailer import and it worked like a charm. :)

Comment: Ah okay, Yeah I'm just reading through it all now, it should solve it I think, thanks alot

Comment: Just thought i'd let you know, I got it working now, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following(for Wampserver):

1->Download [PHPmailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

2->

```
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded        

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail SMTP server(to send messages from GMail)
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                       // 1 = errors and messages
                                       // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->Username   = "YOUR GMAIL EMAIL-ID";
    $mail->Password   = "YOUR GMAIL PASSWORD";

    $mail->SetFrom('YOUR GMAIL ID', 'ANY NAME');

    $mail->AddReplyTo('YOUR GMAIL ID', 'ANY NAME');


    $mail->AddAddress("RECEPIENTS GMAIL ID","ANY NAME");

    $mail->Subject = "ADD SUBJECT";

    $mail->Body ="message";
```

3-> Turn on Extension php_openssl.To turn it on click on WAMP **icon>PHP>PHP Extensions>php_openssl**